# Angular 4 control group validation error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a generic form using Angular reactive forms. I have the following generic Html for a input elements

```
<div class="form-input form-group" [formGroup]="group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 font-label">
            <label>{{ config.label }}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
            <input type="text" [attr.placeholder]="config.placeholder" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"
                [formControlName]="config.name">
            <div [hidden]="!(group.controls[config.name].invalid && group.controls[config.name].touched)">
                <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!group.controls[config.name]?.errors?.required"></small>
                <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!group.controls[config.name]?.errors?.minlength"></small>
                <small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!group.controls[config.name]?.errors?.maxlength"></small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for the following `!group.controls[config.name]?.errors?.required` its telling me `Identifier 'required' is not defined` . Same for `minlength` and `maxlength`. From where i can get `minlength` and `maxlength` and `required errors?`

Comment: Can you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!group.controls[config.name].hasError('required')"></small>
<small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!group.controls[config.name].hasError('minlength')"></small>
<small class="form-text text-danger" [hidden]="!group.controls[config.name].hasError('maxlength')"></small>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the second parameter of [**`AbstractControl#hasError`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#hasError) method using it like this:

```
<small class="form-text text-danger" 
       [hidden]="!group.hasError('required', config.name)">
</small>
```

---

Also, I'd recommend you to use `*ngIf` instead of `hidden`.

[You can read this for a deep explanation](http://angularjs.blogspot.com.br/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html?m=1).